# how to get already opened IE browser handle in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have one already opened IE browser , with some url. 
After this, I Run below code which will open another IE browser. however it gives me only one window handle in below code.
Is it possible to get previously opened IE browser handle ?

```
        IWebDriver IEdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        IReadOnlyCollection<String> browsers = IEdriver.WindowHandles;
        foreach (String item in browsers)
        {
            IEdriver.SwitchTo().Window(item);
            String url = IEdriver.Url;

        }
```

Comment: using Robot class you can navigate to previously opened IE brower

Comment: No, you cannot get the opened IE browser. You can open a new IEDriver or connect to an existing IEDriver and then open a new window.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using C# binding instead of java binding as per your tags?

Comment: YEs, I am using C#

Comment: @Buaban Yes, you thought right way, So it is not possible to already manually opened browser to access using selenium

Comment: you can not get the already open browser with new instance of IE.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
//Do whatever operations you have to do
for(String winHandle : IEdriver.getWindowHandles()){
IEdriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful as what you are trying to do, is not robust solution to write tests cases. If one test case causes browser to crash you will be getting all the test cases failed.

Also I don't think it should be possible to get handles on previously opened window by default, because when you write code

```
    IWebDriver IEdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

It calls for a constructor of InternetExplorerDriver class and opens new instance of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go for close all browsers before starting your test case execution by killing the ie process from task manager.

```
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
```