# How to Handle multiple IE browser instance with coded UI (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, coded-ui-tests, hp-uft

I have two sessions of IE, On first session i have logged to my application with User1 and on second session logged with User2. I need to access (Just edit) one data on the application with these two users simultaneously. I am not able to switch between browsers. Using Visual Studio(2015), .NET(Ver: 4.6), C#(Ver: 6)

Is there any property like browser Creation time or Index similar to QTP?

Note: Test Scenario is to check the application data is editable for both user simultaneously. So handling with one user session at a time is not acceptable

Comment: Each window will have a handle value you should be able to reference to determine which is which.

Comment: How can i get this handle value? I tried object spying both browser session but couldn't find such properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get already opened IE browser handle in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172927/how-to-get-already-opened-ie-browser-handle-in-selenium)

Comment: Coded UI, Selenium and HP-UFT are three different automation tools. Please [edit] the tags on your question to make it clear which one you are using. Remove the tags for the ones you are not using.

Comment: @AdrianHHH : Coded UI is using C#, Selenium with c# also there thats why i tagged Coded UI and selenium groups. Also i have worked with HP-UFT there we have a solution for this question by using "Creation time Or Index" (Already given on question description). So guys who having experience in both UFT and coded UI can easy understand and answer this question, Thats why i added UFT group also into this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a check to be made simultaneously you can try to parallelize your flow. In this case you don't need to care about different instances of your browser.

```
Parallel.ForEach(values, value=>
{
    //your stuff.
});
```

I see 2 ways. If you can get any collection of your browsers then you can set "value" as your collection and then "value" change to "browswer" so you will use it to do whatever you want.

If you don't have colletion of your browsers that you can make this foreach on any fake collection of needed mount of elements and then to run browser instance inside this loop. All the instances will still be run in parallel.